# Inject HttpClient from WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to create a (mostly) unified set of integation tests that can either be targetted at an in-memory API created from a `WebApplicationFactory` or at a fully-deployed version of our app. Using `XUnit.DependencyInjection`, I'm planning on injecting a `HttpClient` into my tests that either points to the test server or the real app based on an environment variable.

So to create a client for the test server, I can just run the following in `Startup.cs`:

```
WebApplicationFactory<Program> app = new();
HttpClient client = app.CreateClient();
```

This seems to work. However, I have absolutely no idea how to inject this implementation for the `HttpClient` into the individual test classes.

Something like this, doesn't work (such an overload doesn't exist):

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyTestClass>(client);
```

And neither does this (the injected client has the `BaseAddress` set to null for some reason):

```
services.AddHttpClient<InMemoryServerSelfTests>(c =>
                                    {
                                        c.BaseAddress           = client.BaseAddress;
                                        c.Timeout               = client.Timeout;
                                    });
```

My only other thought is to create a new class that wraps both clients and inject that instead but that seems messy:

```
public class TestClientWrapper
{
    public readonly HttpClient Client;
    public TestClientWrapper(InMemoryTestServer server)
    {
        Client = server.CreateClient();
    }

    public TestClientWrapper(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }
}

// In Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string targetEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("targetEndpoint"); // Make this configurable
    bool   isLocal        = string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetEndpoint);
    
    if (isLocal)
    {
        InMemoryTestServer app = new();
        services.AddSingleton(new TestClientWrapper(app));
    }
    else
    {
        HttpClient client = new();
        services.AddSingleton(new TestClientWrapper(client));
    }
}
```

So really, I'm a bit stumped... Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `HttpClient` generated by the `WebApplicationFactory` is special as the `WebApplicationFactory` is hosted in memory and is not visible out of process (I think that's what I read elsewhere). What that means is that copying over the settings doesn't work.

The only way I've managed to get the `WebApplicationFactory` client registered so that it is resolvable is to register an instance of `IHttpClientFactory` with the container that returns clients from the `WebApplicationFactory`.

```cs
public class TestHttpClientFactory<TStartup> : IHttpClientFactory 
    where TStartup : class
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> _appFactory;

    public TestHttpClientFactory(WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> appFactory) => _appFactory = appFactory;

    public HttpClient CreateClient(string name) => _appFactory.CreateClient();
}
```

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory>(new TestClientFactory(...));
```

Something along those lines will work.

Comment: I actually went with the wrapper, which worked great. Then I realised that I XUnit DI is just a bit crap, so I'm using CollectionFixtures now which contain the necessary client and webapp... This is a nice solution though, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom `HttpMessageHandlerBuilder` to solve this issue.

```cs
public class TestServerHttpMessageHandlerBuilder : HttpMessageHandlerBuilder
{
    public TestServerHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(TestServer testServer, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        Services = services;
        PrimaryHandler = testServer.CreateHandler();
    }

    private string? _name;

    [DisallowNull]
    public override string? Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(value);
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    public override HttpMessageHandler PrimaryHandler { get; set; }

    public override IList<DelegatingHandler> AdditionalHandlers { get; } = new List<DelegatingHandler>();

    public override IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    public override HttpMessageHandler Build()
    {
        if (PrimaryHandler == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(PrimaryHandler)} must not be null");
        }

        return CreateHandlerPipeline(PrimaryHandler, AdditionalHandlers);
    }
}
```

Then in the startup code register the custom `TestServerHttpMessageHandlerBuilder` BEFORE calling `AddHttpClient`.

```cs
clientServices.AddTransient<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder>(sp => new TestServerHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(webAppFactory.Server, sp));
```

`AddHttpClient` checks if a `HttpMessageHandlerBuilder` was already registered and uses it instead of the default implementation.
Now ALL `HttpClient`s created using the `HttpClientFactory` will use the TestServer.

Answer (score 1):

## Different Scenario:

### Problem:

Consider you have **two** Web/API Applications, and one of them should send requests to the other one, let say I have a FakeApi that I want to call from my `Web` application or you may have an API application that is getting called by a BFF (Backend for Frontend) application.

```
Test -> Main application -> FakeApi
```

```
Test -> BFF -> API
```

How we should tell the target app, to use the second app?

### Solution:

For this, I made my code adapt to the solution that @satnhak provided, although the code had a few issues, so I updated that post as well (if the moderator approves).
So the main code is the same, so give him the credit first.

Okay, in my case I have Gherkin/Specflow Test scenarios and test step definitions.
I have two WebApplicationFactory wrapper per my Web Applications, called `FakeApiWebApplicationFactory` and `MainWebApplicationFactory`.

Considering I'm testing the application in `MainWebApplicationFactory` and it calls to the `FakeApiWebApplicationFactory` for extra services.

For this using the @satnhak code I create a `HttpClientFactory`, and pass it to the `MainWebApplicationFactory` which inside of it I have a service that inject the `HttpClient`, and the HttpClient is added using :

```cs
// Program.cs in Services project
// ---- Program CS should define class if you want to pass it to WebApplicationFactory

builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(myServiceSetting.BaseApiUrl);
});
```

The `MyService` injects an `HttpClient` inside itself, and uses it to connect to the fake or real API.

```cs
public class MyService: IMyService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public GoCardlessBankAccountDataService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

So here are my web factories:

```cs
using FakeApi; // Program.cs in FakeApi project
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;

namespace AcceptanceTests;

public class FakeApiWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // You can modify your configuration here if needed
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // E.g., override some services for testing purposes
        });
    }
}
```

```cs
using Services; // Program.cs in Services project
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace AcceptanceTests;

public class MainWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory? _fakeApiHttpClientFactory;

    public MainWebApplicationFactory(IHttpClientFactory? fakeApiHttpClientFactory)
    {
        _fakeApiHttpClientFactory = fakeApiHttpClientFactory;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        if (_fakeApiHttpClientFactory is not null)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // E.g., override some services for testing purposes
                services.AddSingleton(_fakeApiHttpClientFactory);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code as you can see put a condition, which I believe is
necessary, since I may want to use real service in some of my tests, and I may want to override the HttpClientFactory in some others.

Now I wire these classes as following (Im using Specflow again which in turn it uses the XUnit)
This is the  begining of my test file:

```cs
private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
    
    private readonly FakeApiWebApplicationFactory _fakeApiFactory;
    private readonly HttpClient _fakeApiClient;
    
    private readonly MainWebApplicationFactory _mainFactory;
    private readonly HttpClient _mainClient;

    public MainServiceIntegrationIntegrationStepDefinitions(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        _fakeApiFactory = new FakeApiWebApplicationFactory();
        _fakeApiClient = _fakeApiFactory.CreateClient();

        _mainFactory = new MainWebApplicationFactory(new TestHttpClientFactory<Program>(_fakeApiFactory));
        _mainServicesClient = _mainFactory.CreateClient();
    }
```

As you can see, I first create the FakeApi,
then using @satnhak code, I pass this factory to the Main Service.
Then the main application uses the factory to create an instance of HttpClient that is generated by by the FakeApiWebApiFactory.

**Note:** As I tested you don't need to care about the BaseUrl, as my application sets the BaseUrl as you already scene in the `Problem` section, but the in-memory `HttpClient` made by the `WebApplicationFactory`, still manage to send request to the FakeApi and overcome the customized base Url.

`TestHttpClientFactory`:

```cs
public class TestHttpClientFactory<TStartup> : IHttpClientFactory 
    where TStartup : class
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> _appFactory;

    public TestHttpClientFactory(WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> appFactory) => _appFactory = appFactory;

    public HttpClient CreateClient(string name) => _appFactory.CreateClient();
}
```