# C# ASP.NET, testing websocket with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, websocket

I am currently writing an integration test for a websocket connection. I want to test a ClientWebSocket connection against a server instantiated by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing`. This does not seem to work. Does anybody have an idea how to get this to work?

**My setup is as follows:**

- I have an API application, which offers some normal http endpoints and one websocket
- I have some application code, which establishes a websocket connection
- I have integration tests, which instantiate the API application using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing and use my application code against it

I general am following https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0 . This works great for normal HTTP(S) endpoints. My Code looks like this:

```
_application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder => { });
//HttpClient for http endpoints
_client = _application.CreateClient();
```

The WebSocket endpoint is created as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
   if (context.Request.Path == "/"+nameof(TestModel.WebsocketEvent))
   {
       if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
       {
            TestModel.Instance.WebsocketEvent = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            await ListenForClose(TestModel.Instance.WebsocketEvent);
       }
   }
 }
```

For the connection to the endpoint I am using ClientWebsocket in the code I want to test.

```
 var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
 await ws.ConnectAsync(_href, cancellation);
```

When I run my API application manually and execute my code against that instance, everything works as expected. The WebSocket connection is established.

When I try to run it with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` I get an exception that the server refused the connection.

To some degree it makes sense to me, since the ClientWebSocket is not using anything generated by the WebApplicationFactory.(e.g.  `_application.Server.CreateWebSocketClient`.
On the other Hand I do want to use ClientWebSocket in my code and not inject the WebSocketClient of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing into my production code. In Contrast to http where I actually get a regular HttpClient which I am fine with to inject.

Does anybody have an idea, how I can make the integration test working with ClientWebSocket?
Is there the possiblity to reuse the server Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing starts for requests other than what the WebApplicationFactory generates?
Is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing running the API application at all as a server? Or is there some black magic in the background?

**What I checked so far:**

- _href is correct
- `_application.Server.BaseAddress` does not seem to have an impact

Comment: Your code is working on a local host and not working on a server.  This is a common issue.  You either have a credential issue or you are using HTTP and the server want HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback @jdweng. But the HTTP(S) endpoints are just working fine using the HttpClient generated by the WebApplicationFactory. I am searching for a solution for the websocket endpoint (wss://) using ClientWebSocket class

Comment: Is server also a websocket?  You cannot mix websocket with HTTP.  There is relay code that allow mixing.  The relay has two ports one HTTP and the other websocket.   Did you read the complete webpage on your link?  There are prerequisites that have to apply.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your input. As mentioned in my post both server and client work together for http and websocket if I run them manually in a docker environment or standalone (IIS Express). It just does not work with WebApplicationFactory for integration testing. Therefore I am quite certain that both server code and client code are correct but that there is a problem with the integration test setup. In the integration test setup http endpoints work as expected as well. Only the ClientWebSocket connection is refused.

Comment: I think docker contains a relay.

Comment: Thank you again for your persistent effort to help me @jdweng. My question is very specifically about the instance of my web application generated by WebApplicationFactory. Everything else is working as intended. So anything not related to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing and WebApplicationFactory will not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I want to do is simply not possible. The answer of the following thread pushed me in the right direction.
[Inject HttpClient from WebApplicationFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002621/inject-httpclient-from-webapplicationfactory)

This matches the official documentation if you know what you are looking for:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Hence I can only access the instance of my Web API application using what WebApplicationFactory offers me.
I can't access the instance of the Web API application over my local network.

Thanks to everybody taking the time to read and think about my question.

Comment: As I keep on saying the Network Server is a RELAY and you Local Server is not a relay.